# Why would starting a second X server render Ctrl+Alt+Fn keys unable to switch desktops?

Tags: xorg, fluxbox, enlightenment

I run [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/) 18.8 on [Funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org/Welcome).

Sometimes I want to run a second X server (usually because I'm running a game or other app which might mess up my screen layout).  For this I use simply `startx -- :1`.

My `.xinitrc` is set up to launch fluxbox in that new X server (using `exec startfluxbox`).

It used to be that after starting the second server I could switch between the two using `Ctrl+Alt+F7` and `Ctrl+Alt+F8`.  However, lately it seems that in the second (fluxbox) server none of the `Ctrl+Alt+Fn` keys have any effect.  The only way to get out is to exit fluxbox entirely, at which point I am returned to the enlightenment desktop (where virtual desktop switching works as expected).

Any ideas as to why virtual desktop switching might not work in the second X server?